# How do I make REST calls for a particular Item Amazon.com?

Tags: java, android, http, rest, web-services

Can somebody please show me resources that would let me make REST calls from my Android Phone to Amazon?

I need to get Item details for that Item.

I tried to look for documentation but I really couldn't find it.  I am sorry if this has been answered before but I couldn't find the answer.

Thank you.

Comment: Exactly how far have you gotten and what is blocking you?

Comment: I am sorry. I can't even start because I can't find any documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/GSG/ImplementinganA2SRequest.html for starters? This doesn't use REST though. The [ItemLookup](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/2009-11-01/DG/ItemLookup.html) API call should be the one you need with a `ResponseGroup` of `ItemAttributes`.

You'll need to get set up with access keys - see http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/GSG/GettinganAWSAccessKeyID.html for that.

Not sure if there are any Android-specific issues that you should be aware of